# Do I need buffering in this case, if so, how?

Tags: c, matlab, buffer, nios

I have an issue where the rate the data is sent to serial port (50Hz) is way faster than the serial port can receive (8Hz).

Basically, what I have is, data is sent from fpga vhdl block to NIos II system, Nios II system sends the data to serial port, Matlab access the serial port to real time plot the graph.

I am using Quartus 12.1 sp1, vhdl and Nios II programmed in C code for DE0-Nano. In Qsys, I am using a few cores such as timer, sdram, uart, pios etc.

I dont know if this is feasible. What I am tempted to do, since the rate I can plot a graph is slower than the rate the incoming signal is read.

If I know the beginning of every incoming signal let say this point is indicated by a count=0, everytime I detect count=0, I know it is the beginning of each incoming signal, I keep track of how many cycles, let say, I only want to plot the graph every 10 cycles of the incoming signals, I plot cycle no.1, skip 10 cycles, plot cycle no. 11, skip cycle no.12 to 20, next plot cycle no. 21 etc ...in other words, it means I will lose some cycles in between which I am okay with this.

1. Do you think this method make any sense?
2. Do I still need buffering in this case?
3. How do I know how many cycles I need to skip? I assume it would depend on the incoming signal rate (50 Hz) and plot/receive rate (say 8 Hz), But I am not entirely clear about how to calculate...

The incoming signal  (50 Hz) is from fpga vhdl, NIos system can read at 50 Mhz, but serial port receive rate or Matlab plot rate is 8 Hz.

Appreciate any input...thank you

Comment: Is the data constantly coming in at 50Hz, or are there gaps in between, where no data is sent?

Comment: 1) It is unclear what you are actually asking. 2) What I get from your post is far too broad. This is no forum to discuss ideas, but ask specific questions about programming. If you have any problem with your code, feel free to post a [mcve].

Comment: However, you cannot send 50Hz data on an 8bit/s port unless you remove redundancy. That is a very basic fact.

Comment: Even if you use buffering, at that tortoise rate you'll probably need hardware handshaking.

Comment: Are you really sending data at 50Hz ?  How much data ?  What kind of serial port is limited to 8Hz ? what are the actual Baud rates ?